# Client server communication between two html using node server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, udp

My requirement is:
There are two HTML pages say A and B,
and there is one node server.

So, the use case which I am trying to implement is, "A" sends some message with some payload/parameters , which has to reach "B".

Both A and B are on different IP
As per my knowledge, this may not be achieved without using any intermediate server, so if intermediate server is required, I am looking for node(which internally may use UDP)..

Any heads on or any help for me to start on this will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You may find [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/get-started/) useful. This is easy-to-use Node.js framework for real-time messaging. It uses websockets with AJAX and JSONP fallback.

Comment: I am trying out web sockets for this...will post it if I'll make it work as per my requirement.....Thanks for the suggestion though..